# Cant import models.py in views.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I want to use my model file from my database by importing it in `views.py`. But I get an error when I call a class from `models.py`.

```
ERROR: ImportError: cannot import name Vehicle
```

My path:

```
+ vehicle
---> __init__.py
---> models.py
---> views.py
```

vehicle/models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    plate = models.TextField()
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vehicle'
```

Vehicle/views.py

```
from vehicle.models import Vehicle
s = Vehicle.objects.all()
print s
```

Comment: It should be `from vehicle.models import Vehicle` (with a lowercase `v`)

Comment: I've overlooked it while writing post. I fixed it. Error still going. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Is this the whole code of your views? If not, please provide the rest of it, please

Comment: Have you tried `from .models import Vehicle`?

Comment: i have another error: from .models import Vehicle
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package @HigorRossato

Comment: Yes. I only have these codes to check if the database is working properly. @HigorRossato

Comment: Have you register your app in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes. i added this ''vehicle.apps.vehicleConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS. is it true? @HigorRossato

Comment: It's correct indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling model in view, you can call it directly

```py
from model import Vehicles
```

If you want to have a full path, you can add the location of vehicles on your Path

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path_to_vehicle_folder')

from vehicles.model import Vehicles
```

The way you are doing now, assumes that your execution happens outside vehicles directlory

```sh
vehicles\
    __init__.py
    model.py
    view.py
this.py
```

In `this.py` you can import as you did.

You can always execute `print(sys.path)`, to see where your python is going to look for packages/modules :) with the `sys.path.insert`,  we add a location we want to include when looking for modules. There exists better ways :)